# InstallShield gives build error after adding localized resources in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, installshield-le

I just started using InstallShield LE and am about to give up and search for alternatives.

I have a Winforms project which uses localized forms. When I don't add localized resources in InstallShield, everything works OK, but the forms only appear in English (default language). I assume this is because I didn't add localized resources to my InstallShield Application Files.

However, when I do add those files, I get a build error on the InstallShield project. The message is cryptic: -6100 Internal Build Failure. If I remove the localized resources, everything builds fine.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have run into the same problem.

Comment: I did resolve it but I don't know how. I might have just created the project from scratch.